# xxPython comment multiple line not working in array

Tags: python

For example:
I have

```
array = [\
1,
2,
3,
4
]
```

I want to comment out 2 and 3
This works:

```
array = [\
1,
#2,
#3,
4
]
```

This does not:

```
array = [\
1,
'''
2,
3,
'''
4
]
```

Now imagine that array is huge. hundreds of lines. I cannot find a easy way to do it unless use some editor trick.
I cannot believe that Python as a language does not have something that works for multiple lines of comment properly.
Again, the fact it does not have {} is way messed up than this.
Please point out how this should be done and that I'm too stupid to find it with Google.

-- EDIT 2 --
I agree with everyone that store data this way is not ideal. But I have some existing bad code. I need to deal quickly to figure out the problem. Let's face it, we've all been there unless you never worked in a real job. Any other language I worked with before have syntax to block comment multiple lines that works anywhere in the code. Don't anyone feel this is a problem for Python?

Comment: If you have that big an array (hundreds of lines), I would be of the opinion that the problem is with the way you store data, and not with the way python comments work.

Comment: Any halfway-decent IDE will let you comment out an arbitrary number of lines, it's hardly a *"trick"*. Also, read [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008).

Comment: Triple quoting creates a string, it doesn't create a comment; [Python docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) are not comments.

Comment: is this a real array or text?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: It's a real array in the OP's Python script, so modifying it with string processing is (probably) not appropriate... :)

Comment: But python DOES have { }.  They are used to indicate a dictionary or a set.  Or do you mean that python syntax is different to the language you know?  Of course it is, otherwise it wouldn't be python.  You could always `from __future__ import braces`

Answer (score 8):

You are using it wrong.

`'''` is multi line string syntax. It is not for commenting alone. Because of string converstion you are not getting your output.

Edit:

While

```
array = [\
1,
#2,
#3,
4
]
```

gets read as

```
array = [\
1,
4
]
```

---

```
array = [\
1,
'''
2,
3,
'''
4
]
```

gets read as

```
array = [\
1,
"\n2,\n3,\n"
4
]
```

---

Because of this we see a syntax error.

---

What i have discovered myself just now is that

```
array = [\
1,
"""
2,
3,
"""
,4]
```

Works :) as it gets read like:

```
array = [\
1,
"\n2,\n3,\n",
4]
```

To verify this do a:

```
print array
```

Comment: As I said in my comment on the question, Python docstrings are **not** comments.

Comment: You are right @PM 2Ring. I hope some new commenting style get introduced to solve this problem :)

Comment: Thanks @Bhargav Rao, you are an eye opener :)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that you do not have even a half-decent editor with commenting functionality, and suppose that this is the only way to do it in the large file. If you do `"""..."""` it will create a multiline string literal. Now, if everything in your array that is of interest are *numbers* or anything that is *not* string, it is your lucky day:

```
array = [
1,
2,
"""
3,
4
""",  # this comma must be here
5
]
```

Notice that now your array is actually `[1, 2, '\n3,\n4\n', 5]`, that is, there is a multiline string among the data. Now you can weed out any *strings* in your array by doing:

```
array = [ i for i in array if not isinstance(i, str) ]
```

to get `[1, 2, 5]`.

Of course this does not come without overhead, so I would rather go for an "editor trick".